# org.w3c.dom.Document gwt converter to string in GWT

Tags: gwt, dom

I have a problem when I try converter a document (org.w3c.dom.Document) to String for GWT.

Bofer I developed it without to use GWT and I make like this:

```
        XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
        StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
        OutputFormat outFormat1 = new OutputFormat();

        outFormat1.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        //outFormat1.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        outFormat1.setVersion("1.0");
        outFormat1.setIndenting(true);

        outFormat1.setIndent(4);
        //outFormat1.setIndent(2);
        outFormat1.setOmitXMLDeclaration(false);

        outFormat1.setMethod("xml");


        xmlSerializer.setOutputCharStream(strWriter);
        xmlSerializer.setOutputFormat(outFormat1);
        xmlSerializer.serialize(xmlDoc);
        strWriter.close();
```

But the application give a mistake because GWT don´t accept it.

Do someone know some other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to deal with xml documents in client side, right?

If so, you cannot use org.w3c.dom since it is not part of the subset of the [java runtime library emulated by gwt](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation).

To handle xml in client-side you have to use [GWT XML parsers](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML), or another client library, personally I prefer the [gwtquery XML data-binding](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/DataBinding#XML) way.